# unix stat command trailing zeros after seconds

Tags: unix

How can I remove the many zeros (0000000 +0000) after the seconds in the output for stat command in unix

```
filetime=$(stat --format=%y fileName.txt)
echo $filetime

2016-01-27 15:03:26.000000000 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for size

```
filetime=$(stat --format=%y fileName.txt | sed 's/.000000000//')
echo $filetime

2016-01-27 15:03:26 +0000
```